# Can't Open Android Device Monitor - Reinstall?

Tags: android, windows, android-device-monitor

Like others, when I open Android Device Monitor I get the error:

"An error has occurred. See the log file
C:\Users\Me.android\monitor-workspace.metadata.log."

When I looked in the log file, the error was:

```
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.android.ddmuilib.logcat.LogCatPanel.updateUnreadCount(LogCatPanel.java:1212)
```

I tried some quick solutions others found:

- Running as Administrator (I'm on Windows)
- echo $JAVA_HOME outputs a location (and I think it's there), but need to check this out more

This worked until just yesterday, so I am worried I may have accidentally uninstalled or deleted something (just did some clean-up).

How can I reinstall Android Device Monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened SDK Manager and deleted the most recent 3 tools, then I reinstalled them. That seems to have fixed it. It did take a while, so it might be worth trying only uninstalling the most recent set of tools.